# How do you change the iOS app icon background color during launch animation?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, launch, appicon

When launching a flutter built iOS application, I briefly get this black background surrounding the launch screen. How would you change the black background depicted in the image? I tried changing the launch screen background color in Xcode, but I still get this black "border".

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: What black border? This image doesn’t appear to be showing a launch screen.

Comment: @LouFranco I updated the post with more images.

Comment: Did you check with the release build ?

Comment: Yes, same problem. I'm porting an application that was natively developed on iOS to flutter, and that application has the same problem. I'm a bit unfamiliar with iOS development, but I will dig around if this is unresolved whenever I get to the publishing stages.

Comment: Make a very simple launch screen storyboard and see what happens (just all white).  Then slowly build it back up to what it was until you find out what caused it.

Answer (score 3):

The black "border" in the opening app animation has to do with the way the default flutter icons were generated. I generated my own icons using this [generator](https://appicon.co), and the app animates as intended.